# SSRS CountIf Formula Equivalent to achieve distinct count based on value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to find an equivalent formula that is like COUNTIF in Excel in SSRS to achieve a distinct cound based on a change in value,

For example below I can achieve this numbering for Line Number in Excel by using the following formula;  =COUNTIF($A$2:A2, A2)

[Excel example - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBpt0.jpg)
Any ideas how you can do this in SSRS?

Thanks heaps!!

---

Thank you for this, however it isn't giving me what I was hoping to achieve.

This is the result that I get using the following formula, I just get a value of 1 in each row.

=CountDistinct(Fields!INVOICE_NUMBER.Value)

[Image of results of adding formula in SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbwsO.jpg)

This image below is what I am trying to ultimately achieve, in Excel I can achieve this by;

=COUNTIF($C$2:C2, C2)

[Image of results of adding formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuxJh.jpg)

Any suggestions, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count with a condition you can use

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!YourConditionField.Value = "NotBlue", Nothing, 1))
```

If you just want to count distinct values (every value just once) you can use

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!YourCountField.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however it isn't giving me what I was hoping to achieve.

This is the result that I get using the following formula, I just get a value of 1 in each row. 

=CountDistinct(Fields!INVOICE_NUMBER.Value)

![Image of results of adding formula](http://i67.tinypic.com/2e328n8.jpg).

This image below is what I am trying to ultimately achieve, in Excel I can achieve this by;

=COUNTIF($C$2:C2, C2)  

![Image of results of adding formula](http://i66.tinypic.com/ncfigj.jpg).

Any suggestions, Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm ok now I know what you want. But I dont think you can do it like that in SSRS. Normally for such a problem you would group the table by the column _Invoice Number_ ("InvoiceNumberGroup") and then in the grouped tablix use `=Count(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value, "InvoiceNumberGroup")` so you get every Invoice Number just once with the amount

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing in ssrs try to change dataset by using row_number 
like this - row_number() over(partition by  INVOICE_NUMBER order by 
INVOICE_NUMBER  asc) as rownum